# message push system facebook style

Tags: javascript, facebook, push

I'm working at a community site for a friends mmo-guild, just to increase my skills and learn new techniques. 
my idea is to build a message/notification/whatever push system alâ facebook style. that means if someone sends you a message, a new post in the board appears or something similar you get a little notification just like facebook uses it (you get a little red number in your userbar at the top of the page).

now i don't know what to google for. is a "push system" the right definition for this?
how could i do it?
i also looked in different questions and read about node.js and comet.
The concept of these technologies is clear to me (from other languages, like Java)

So you have (e.g. node.js) server which pushes a message (if available) to the client. how do i handle such a push on a client? i need something like a listener, do i?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this [realtime web technology guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) a good starting point if you have a particular back-end technology in mind e.g. search for 'php' or 'ruby' for find a hosted or self-hosted realtime technology.

> how do i handle such a push on a client?
>   i need something like a listener, do i?

The paradigm frequently used with all this technologies is [PubSub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). PubSub is achieved on the client in different ways with different technologies.

The technology you use to communicate between the client and server varies between solution but the move is very much towards the best approach being WebSocket. However, the libraries used by the realtime web technology you choose will abstract away from using WebSockets directly.

I'll demonstrate how you would subscribe to data using the [Pusher](http://pusher.com) JavaScript library:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('YOUR_APP_KEY'); // connect
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(eventData) {
  // handle event data
});
```

Pusher use [channels](http://pusher.com/docs/channels) and it's a commonly used term, but other technologies refer to these as topics or subjects. Channels can be used to filter data or be specific to a particular topic e.g. 'my_football_team' and events are a way of filtering data further e.g. 'new_news_item', 'score_update'.

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques to do a "push" from the server to the browser. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

For a guild website that is your first attempt at doing this, it will probably be easiest to just periodically poll the server with an XMLHttpRequest and update the page content if there is new data.

Once that works, you can change it into a continuous "long poll", which gets answered by the server only when there is new data, thus reducing network traffic and making the notifications more instantaneous.